# How to rotate 90 clockwise (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, rotation, cgrect

This 2 lines of code produce a image that is 90 counter clockwise from the way i took the image. Any ideas how I can use code to rotate the image 90 degrees clockwise?

```
  let l = photoDispaly.image

      l?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 10, y: 240.5, width: 435 , height: 435), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: The code you provided don't make the image rotate at all

Comment: I know but this is how the image is printed and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the image view 90 degrees clockwise through this line of code.

```
yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```